# Why does this split function work?

Tags: recursion, f#

I have function that splits a list into two halfs.

Here is the function :

```
  let rec split = function
  | []       -> ([],[])
  | [a]      -> ([a],[])
  | a::b::cs -> let (M,N) = split cs
                (a::M, b::N)
```

What I don't understand is why this statement works `(a::M, b::N)`. Aren't we calling the recursive function before we execute that statement? So should't that statement never be executed?

Comment: Try writing down the execution flow for a short list and you'll see how it works. At some point you'll start matching `[]` and `[a]` which will cause the recursion to unroll all the way up to the first call.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I was doing it incorrectly and that is why I was getting confused, but now I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: All that is happening is that your function is not tail recursive. (In a tail recursive function the recursion call is the last thing in the function). F# can handle non-tail recursive functions. However, since your function is not tail recursive, if you provide a long list the stack will blow up. Just try it with this list: `let xs = [1..1000000]`. To fix this you have to rewrite your function using the accumulation pattern (or some other technique) so that it becomes tail recursive. Tail recursive functions do not blow the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Aren't we calling the recursive function before we execute that statement?

Yes.

> So should't that statement never be executed?

Only if the recursion were infinite, which it is not. As is, `(a::M, b::N)` will be evaluated once the recursive call finishes.

As an example, consider the call `split [1;2;3]`:

```
  split [1;2;3]
= let (M,N) = split [3]
  (1::M, 2::N)
= let (M,N) = ([3], [])
  (1::M, 2::N)
= (1::[3], 2::[])
= ([1;3], [2])
```

Nothing infinite going on here.

Comment: I was doing the example incorrectly, which is why I was getting confused. Thank you for your help!